# Link clarity in code tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, formatting

Sometimes it is useful to link directly to documentation for a specific function in your questions/answers. And in many cases, one will often want to put the function name in `` tags, like this: "[`FuncName`][1]".

On Stack Overflow, this looks fine; the linked text in the code tags appears blue. On GDSE however, it's impossible to tell the difference between [`glDrawArrays`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawArrays) and `glDrawArrays` without mouse-overing them. We should use better text coloring to tell the difference.

Is there any movement on this? Or even acknowledgement? Does this need to be asked on MSO?

Comment: I agree, this would be a nice fix. I find myself just adding fluff. Like, "use `glDrawArrays`([link](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawArrays))"

Comment: I made a similar complaint several months ago, but it never received much attention. http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/967/link-colors-for-visited-and-non-visited-links-too-similar

Comment: Which, if we combine the upvotes from my post and this one, now has a total of 16 people who really do think this change is positive.  In terms of accessibility, GDSE is far too difficult to read effectively with its bland color palette.  This is even worse on Meta because all the colors were made muted/gray, further reducing the value of the colors.

Comment: @Byte56: Is there something that can be done to speed a fix like this along?

Comment: I'll bring it up to some people with some power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this on dev, the change will be on live after our next production build. I've made the links underlined if they appear inside of a code block(same for code block inside of a link as well)

Comment: Looks good, thanks.